# Amazon Athena allow view access and deny table access

Tags: amazon-athena, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I need to hide some fields from a table to a certain group of users.

I thought about the creation of a **view** that allows me to mask those fields. However, once the permissions are set to only grant access to the view, the queries fail because they also need access to the table that is being queried under the view.

Is there a way (or condition) that allows me to grant access to the **view** but **deny access to the table** used in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Column-level permissions will be supported as part of [AWS lake formation](https://aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/features/). It is still on preview, but you can request access.

Answer (score 0):

As Lake formation is only available in a specific region in beta test, for now you need to duplicate the data, or wait.